# SLURM/sbatch: How to pass both a pointer to my data and the SLURM job ID to a job script

Tags: arrays, slurm, sbatch

I am using a job array to process a large number of files, and I am able to pass a pointer from my array to the specific data file to be processed in the job script, but I want to also pass the specific SLURM job ID to the script and I can't seem to find the correct syntax to do so.

My array script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ============================================
#SBATCH --job-name=sortdata
...
#SBATCH --output=down1count/sort_%A_%a.txt
#SBATCH --array=0-99
# ============================================
SIZE=30
INDEX_FILE="down1list.txt"

IDXZERO=$(( SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID * SIZE ))
IDXBEG=$(( IDXZERO + 1 ))
IDXEND=$(( IDXBEG + SIZE - 1 ))

for IDX in $(seq $IDXBEG $IDXEND); do
        DATA=$(sed -n ${IDX}p $INDEX_FILE)       
        sortfile1.bash $DATA      
done
```

where `down1list.txt` is just a list of the files in the directory created by `ls down1/ >> down1list.txt`.

The relevant part of my job script `sortfile1.bash` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "down1/$@"; do
    gunzip $file 

    ###do some more stuff with the file####

done
```

What I would like to do is utilize my cluster's larger file system storage but it can only be accessed through my `${SLURM_JOB_ID}`.  Then I would `mv` the file before I unzip it in the above code.  I've looked at a bunch of different questions and answers on this site and I can't seem to find anything that covers the syntax I am missing.

I believe by using `$@` I ought to be able to access the `${SLURM_JOB_ID}` but I can't figure out how to add it correctly to the `sortfile1.bash $DATA` line or how I would call it in my `sortfile1.bash` code.  I tried just adding it directly like this: `sortfile1.bash $DATA %A_%a` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${SLURM_JOB_ID}` environment variable should be visible from all programs that are part of the job. So you should be able to simply use it directly in the code of `sortfile1.bash`.

Should that be not the case, the usual approach would be to pass the variable as the first argument and use the `shift` keyword to skip it once its value has be stored in another variable, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

JID=$1
shift

for file in "down1/$@"; do
    gunzip $file 

    ###do some more stuff with the file####

done
```

and call it like this in the submission script:

```
sortfile1.bash $SLURM_JOB_ID $DATA
```

After `shift` is called, `$@` will hold the list of arguments except for the first one, each being "shifted" `$2` -> `$1`, `$3`->`$2`, etc.